# Add regular json to jstree?

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I've just happened onto the jstree library.  Looks like a great resource, but I've having trouble getting my data (It's plain ol' json) into the fancy format (with states, icons, children, etc.) that jstree seems to require.

For example, suppose I have the json object:

```
{
    "A" : [1,2,3],
    "B" : {
        "x" : 4,
        "y" : 5,
        "z" : 6
    }
}
```

It seems like there ought to be a straightforward way to convert this into the format that jstree wants, with 1,2, and 3 as children to A, and x, y, and z as children of B.  But I haven't been able to find one.

Is this possible?  How?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If our three is static then you have to do it once manually
- If your tree is dynamic you have to write a code to that

Comment: Please explain. With an example if possible.

Comment: Which part do you need to be explained?

Comment: How do you load a tree dynamically without using the jstree ajax model? How do you create a branch and add it to an already loaded tree?

Comment: I don't have experience with that. I reckon it can be done programatically. Why don't you want to use ajax?

Comment: This seems like a big limitation in the jstree library.  Maybe my use case is weird, but it seems like the first thing you'd want to do with the library: map it to a useful data structure without a lot of headache.  Here's a different tool that does more of what I want: http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/online-json-tree-viewer/#

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it manually.